# Form post tag missing

Tags: 7, forms

I am writing a module which uses a template to output results from a database; these results can be edited. I use a form with a fieldset of submit buttons. Each result has an edit button. I get the buttons rendered but there is no `<form>` tag so nothing happens when the buttons are hit.
Below is my code. I believe I am missing something fundamental, or there is a better way to do it.

```
  function eventhistory_menu() {
    $items['personal-history'] = array(
      'title' => 'Event history',
      'page callback' => 'historypage_rendered',
      'access callback' => TRUE,
    );

    return $items;
  }

  function eventhistory_theme() {
    return array(
      'eventhistory_template' => array(
        'variables' => array('output' => NULL, 'hist_form' => NULL),
        'template' => 'eventhistory_template',
      ),
    );
  }


  function historypage_rendered() {
    $output = array(
      '#theme' => 'eventhistory_template',
      '#type' => 'markup',
      '#hist_form' => drupal_get_form('historyEdit_form'), 
      '#output' => getHistory(),
    );

    return $output;
  }

 function historyEdit_form($form, &$form_state) {
   $form['#tree'] = TRUE;
   $num_hist = 0;

   $form['history']  = array(
     '#type' => 'fieldset',
   );

   if ($form_state['hist_num']) {
     for ($i = 1; $i <= $form_state['hist_num']; $i++) {
       $form['history']['num' . $i] = array(
         '#value' => 'Edit',
         '#type' => 'submit',
       );
     }
   }

   return $form;
 }
```

In the template I have `print drupal_render($hist_form['history']['num' . $count]);`. The buttons show, but they are not surrounded by any `<form>` tag.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your way of implementation is partially wrong. Please try it like that:

```
function eventhistory_menu() {
  $items['personal-history'] = array(
    'title' => 'Event history',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('eventhistory_edit_form'),
    'theme callback' => 'eventhistory_template',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
  );

  return $items;
}

function eventhistory_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return array(
    'eventhistory_template' => array(
      'variables' => array('output' => NULL, 'hist_form' => NULL),
      'template' => 'eventhistory_template',
    ),
  );
}


function eventhistory_edit_form($form, &$form_state) {
 $form['#tree'] = TRUE;
 $num_hist = 0;

 $form['history']  = array(
   '#type' => 'fieldset',
 );

 if ($form_state['hist_num']) {
   for ($i = 1; $i <= $form_state['hist_num']; $i++) {
     $form['history']['num' . $i] = array(
       '#value' => 'Edit',
       '#type' => 'submit',
     );
   }
 }

 return $form;
}
```

I've discarded the `historypage_rendered` function from your code and called the form directly in [`hook_menu`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) implementation. I also added the `theme callback` to `hook_menu`, and also renamed your form function to follow [Drupal coding standards](https://drupal.org/coding-standards).

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I used your approach but my theme template was not getting called. Anyway I removed the theme callback and implemented the form theme in the module and it works. Also note the page arguments takes an array.

Comment: Glad that you've got it working. I've corrected the usage of 'page arguments'